# How to Pass a method as props for an element in react

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an Error when I want to pass a function into my function Component in `React`. where is the problem?

I have started learning `React` and I am watching a tutorial. I have very simple function component with only one `<p>` element, also I have a simple function in my App.js, everything works fine but when I am going to pass my function from App.js to my Function component I get an Error.

Well, I did the same as the tutorial. Although, everything is OK in the tutorial (as per Video) it does not work for me.

Could someone help me, and let me know what the problem is?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Person from './Person/Person';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    person: [
      { namd: "Ehsan", age: 36 },
      { name: "Mosen", age: 48 }
    ]
  }

  swichNameHandler = (newName) => {
    this.setState({
      person: [
        { name: newName, age: 37 },
        { name: "Mohsen", age: 49 }
      ]
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>this is react</h1>
        <button onClick={this.swichNameHandler.bind(this, "ehsan")}>Click Here</button>
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[0].name}
          age={this.state.person[0].age}
          click={this.swichNameHandler} />
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[1].name}
          age={this.state.person[1].age}
          click={this.swichNameHandler}> he is my brother.</Person>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

```
import React from 'react';

//Create a new Component
const person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p onClick={props.click}> My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old.</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default person;
```

and this is the Error when I click on p element:

> react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a
>   React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst,
>   _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances, nativeEvent, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp,
>   defaultPrevented, isTrusted, view, detail, screenX, screenY, clientX,
>   clientY, pageX, pageY, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey,
>   getModifierState, button, buttons, relatedTarget, movementX,
>   movementY, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped})

If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: _From quick review :_
your **swichNameHandler** function is expecting one parameter but you are not passing any parameter on that function when creating a **Person** Component.

_Quick Solution:_
Just pass a parameter to function.
Example:
 `<Person
          name={this.state.person[0].name}
          age={this.state.person[0].age}
          click={() =>{this.swichNameHandler("New Name")}} />`

Comment: tnx, well done!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is typo in your state , where person[0] should be "name" but you have written "namd" , Which causes person[0].name to be undefined and hence the error is thrown

```
 state = {
    person: [
      { namd: "Ehsan", age: 36 },
      { name: "Mosen", age: 48 }
    ]
  }
```

should be

```
 state = {
    person: [
      { name: "Ehsan", age: 36 },
      { name: "Mosen", age: 48 }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: tnx, that was another issue, but it does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In react you should wrap childrens inside parent element such as div etc.

```
<div>
 <p>{props.children}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your component name

Change your component name from :

```
// Wrong! This is a component and should have been capitalized:
const person = (props) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p onClick={props.click}> My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old.</p>
                    <p>{props.children}</p>
                </div>
            )
        }

export default person; 

to: // and check your event like below : 

const Person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p onClick={() => props.click(props.name)}> My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old.</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Person
```

Component Name should start with capital, In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. However, lower-case tag names with a dot (property accessor) aren't.  [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jn92uu)

Comment: I fix my mistake, but still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the function you are using:
Your App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Person from './Person';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    person: [
      { namd: "Ehsan", age: 36 },
      { name: "Mosen", age: 48 }
    ]
  }

  swichNameHandler = (newName) => {
    this.setState({
      person: [
        { name: newName, age: 37 },
        { name: "Mohsen", age: 49 }
      ]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>this is react</h1>
        <button onClick={this.swichNameHandler.bind(this, "ehsan")}>Click Here</button>
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[0].name}
          age={this.state.person[0].age}
          click={this.swichNameHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is your person.js

```
import React from 'react';

//Create a new Component
const person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p> My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old.</p>
            <button onClick={() => props.click('Your new name')}>Button</button>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default person;
```

Comment: I did what said man, but it still does not work, Same problem!

Comment: Hope you are not missing anything, check it again and this how we use functions that we pass as props

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working codepen of your application. If you want to make some changes let me know.

https://codepen.io/eseinv/pen/KJvoVB

```
const Person = props => {
return (
    <div>
        <p> My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old.</p>
        <p>{props.children}</p>
    </div>
)
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    person: [
      { name: "Ehsan", age: 36 },
      { name: "Mohsen", age: 48 }
    ]
  }

switchNameHandler = newName => {
  this.setState({
    person: [
      { name: newName, age: 37 },
      { name: "Mohsen", age: 49 }
  ]
})
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>this is react</h1>
      <button onClick={() => this.switchNameHandler("ehsan")}>Click Here</button>
      <div onClick={() => this.switchNameHandler('Name')}>
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[0].name}
          age={this.state.person[0].age}
        />
      </div>
      <div onClick={() => this.switchNameHandler('Name')}>
        <Person
          name={this.state.person[1].name}
          age={this.state.person[1].age} >
        he is my brother.</Person>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```